# cocos 2d-x-3.5 error while building apk: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x, eof

```
building apk
Please input the absolute/relative path of ".keystore" file:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py", line 859, in <module>
    run_plugin(command, argv, plugins)
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py", line 817, in run_plugin
    plugin.run(argv, dependencies_objects)
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\project_compile\project_compile.py", line 1432, in run
    self.build_android()
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\project_compile\project_compile.py", line 440, in build_android
    self.apk_path = builder.do_build_apk(sdk_root, ant_root, build_mode, output_dir, self._custom_step_args, self)
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\project_compile\build_android.py", line 382, in do_build_apk
    self._gather_sign_info()
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\project_compile\build_android.py", line 429, in _gather_sign_info
    inputed = self._get_user_input("Please input the absolute/relative path of \".keystore\" file:")
  File "C:\Android\cocos2d-x-3.5\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\project_compile\build_android.py", line 458, in _get_user_input
    ret = raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Please use cocos console instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Android/Game/proj.android/build_native.py", line 43, in <module>
    build(opts.build_mode)
  File "C:/Android/Game/proj.android/build_native.py", line 28, in build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ C:\Android\Game\proj.android\../ ] fails!
```

I'm trying to build HelloWorld project in Eclipse but it gives me this error, here's what apparently causes this problem (in build_android.py):

```
def _get_user_input(self, tip_msg):
        cocos.Logging.warning(tip_msg)
        ret = None
        while True:
            ret = raw_input()
            break

        return ret
```

I can't understand exactly why it is failing.

Comment: Did you input .keystore file path correctly?

Comment: where i can check/do it?

Comment: It seems that the build script is asking you for the .keystore file path, try to just type it in.

Comment: but it's not asking, only saying something is wrong so i don't know where to type that path in

Answer (score 1):

I test cocos2dx 3.6, 3.5, 3.4 . A all of them are failed.
Especially when I try version 3.5, I got same error to yours.

Now I success build my project. Belows are my method.

First, I change tools version to below things. And change environment variables to fit them.

```
cocos2dx 3.4
NDK r9d
```

But I had got errors too.
So,

Second, I remove cocos2dx sdk 3.4 folder and re-unzipped.
At this time, Environment variables have been already made. So I didn't run `setup.py` and `download-deps.py`.
I think that when first cocos project build, cocos's references to environment variables is fixed. So If you change 'env var' after first build, it wouldn't refreshed automatically.

Third, Remake cocos project and import to eclipse and build.

Finally, My projects are working now well.

I suggest you to delete and re-install coco2dx framework.
If it don't work, Change cocos2dx version or ndk version. And delete and re-install coco2dx framework. It demand much time. But in some try, you will succeed.

Sorry for my poor english. But I really want share test-case that work fine for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem so I opened bash_profile and deleted everything in it,
then ran through setup.py again and reinput ndk and sdk paths, recompile and run ... and everything worked fine!